# What does ' self signed certificate' mean?

Tags: security, ssl, certificate

I want to understand what `self signed certificate` means.

any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: It's a certificate you have created yourself without anyone validating it. See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate page for a much more in-depth explanation

Comment: Might be a better fit to https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd comment on how a simple google search would have answered that, but I don't want to appear naive. Is there something in specific that you don't understand about them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self Signed Certificates are types of SSL certificates that are generated by an independent person (such as yourself), rather than generated by a [Certificate Authority](https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/what-are-certification-authorities-trust-hierarchies/).

Many organizations are tempted to use self-signed SSL Certificates instead of those issued and verified by a trusted Certificate Authority mainly because of the price difference. Unlike CA issued certificates, self-signed certificates are free of charge. What most users are not aware of is that self-signed certificates can end up costing them more in the long run.

While self-signed SSL Certificates also encrypt customers' log in and other personal account credentials, they prompt most web servers to display a security alert because the certificate was not verified by a trusted Certificate Authority. Often the alerts advise the visitor to abort browsing the page for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

In cryptography and computer security, a self-signed certificate is an identity certificate that is signed by the same entity whose identity it certifies. This term has nothing to do with the identity of the person or organization that actually performed the signing procedure.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the people who are providing the certificate are the same people the certificate is being issued to, usually done this way because it is free.
It is best to have a certificate provided by a trusted Certificate Authority however, It will cost money, but is more trustworthy.